# tcpdump on debian 8

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I had installed tcpdump on debian 8 via the apt-get command.  When I try to record packet on a monitoring interface which gets packets via SPAN port with the following command ***"tcpdump -i interface -nn -c 25"*** I can see both traffic going to a webserver and webserver reponding back to the client.

However when I try to write those packets to a file like ***"tcpdump -i interface -nn -w file.pcap -s 0"*** and then attempt to read the file like ***"tcpdump -i interface -r file.pcap 'host x.x.x.x'"*** I can see only one side of the communication. That is the webserver responding back to the client.  Has any one face this situation before?

I know that both sides of conversation are recorded in the file.pcap because I am able to retrieve both sides of the conversation via tshark however not via tcpdump.

Comment: Try `tcpdump -nn -r file.pcap` it should show both sides

Comment: I cannot do it without a filter because the pcap file is over 700MB in size.